# How can I prevent unwanted calls to ListView.getView()?

Tags: android, listview

I am using a custom `ListView` with images and `EditText` in my activity. When I click any clickable button outside the `ListView` it calls the `getView()` function of the `ListView`. How can I prevent this?

Comment: it shouldn't. care to show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't want to call or refresh listview on button click.

`getView()` will be called many, many times, for all sorts of things, including events outside the `ListView` itself. You need `getView()` to be fast and idempotent (i.e., if called twice with the same inputs and same environment returns the same result).